# How to make a custom sort order in mySQL and check the beginning of the strings?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I found a couple of [questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql%20custom%20order) that deal with custom sorting, custom sort alphabets. However, I could not find the solution to my issue.

Imagine we have a table like that:

```
 # videoid #
 F01
 F02
 F031
 F032
 G01
 G02
 GEO01
 PR011
 PR012
 TRI01
 TRI021
 TRI022
 VEK01
```

and we would like to sort it non-alphabetic, instead of A-Z it should be G, F, GEO, TRI, PR, VEK. For this I have to define the custom sorting plus consider the `%` wildcard to fetch all results that start with e.g. "F".

I tried mysql's `CASE` `WHEN` query but it does not seem to work when there is a LIKE compare:

```
SELECT * FROM `videos`
ORDER BY CASE `videoid`
    WHEN videoid LIKE 'G%' THEN 1
    WHEN videoid LIKE 'F%' THEN 2
    WHEN videoid LIKE 'GEO%' THEN 3
    WHEN videoid LIKE 'TRI%' THEN 5
    WHEN videoid LIKE 'PR%' THEN 4
    WHEN videoid LIKE 'VEK%' THEN 6
    ELSE 0
END
```

My attempt with

```
WHEN (LEFT(videoid, 1) = 'G') THEN 1
WHEN (LEFT(videoid, 1) = 'F') THEN 2
WHEN (LEFT(videoid, 3) = 'GEO') THEN 3
...
```

failed too.

I also tried to use `FIELD` without success:

```
SELECT * FROM `videos`
ORDER BY FIELD(videoid, 'G%','F%','GEO%','TRI%','PR%','VEK%');
```

What would be the correct mysql query?

Comment: Post your table on SQLFiddle.com and show us.

Comment: @Ravinder: I'm new to sql fiddle, my attempt does not output the query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a5cf0/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM `videos`
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN `videoid` LIKE 'GEO%' THEN 3
WHEN `videoid` LIKE 'G%' THEN 1
WHEN `videoid` LIKE 'F%' THEN 2
WHEN `videoid` LIKE 'TRI%' THEN 4
WHEN `videoid` LIKE 'PR%' THEN 5
WHEN `videoid` LIKE 'VEK%' THEN 6
ELSE 0
END
```

This might be helpful to you.

Comment: This wont even compile.

Comment: Thanks Ankit, but I get a mysql error message with your query: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE 'G%' THEN 1
WHEN LIKE 'F%' THEN 2
WHEN LIKE 'GEO%' THEN 3
WHEN LIKE 'TRI%' ' at line 3 `

Comment: Thanks, that works! So my mistake was to mention the videoid in `ORDER BY CASE `videoid``.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following.  Try it at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6239/12)

```
create table videos (
  videoid varchar(8) not null,
  video varchar(8)
)engine=InnoDB;

INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('F01', 'F01');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('F02', 'F02');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('F031', 'F031');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('F032', 'F032');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('G01', 'G01');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('G02', 'G02');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('GEO01', 'GEO01');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('PR011', 'PR011');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('PR012', 'PR012');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('TRI01', 'TRI01');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('TRI021', 'TRI021');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('TRI022', 'TRI022');
INSERT into videos(videoid, video) values('VEK01', 'VEK01');

select videoid, video
  , case
     when videoid like 'GEO%' then 3
     when videoid like 'F%' then 2
     when videoid like 'G%' then 1
     when videoid like 'PR%' then 4
     when videoid like 'TRI%' then 5
     when videoid like 'VEK%' then 6
    end v_ord
from videos
order by v_ord, videoid;
```